# How to grey out JButton in Java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton

How can I grey in/out a Swing Jbutton? What method can I use? Also, how can I make it greyed out by default in Netbeans?

Comment: See the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```

The above should grey out a button just fine. I would make sure you have the documentation bookmarked or downloaded and read up on it a bit

**Edit**

My assumption is that you are using the GUI creator in Netbeans. I would highly advise reading up on swing and learning the language rather than the IDE (there could be times when you have to use a different IDE than Netbeans and wouldn't have a clue how to do GUIs)